# How to access Individual elements of an object list which converted from a LINQ operation after passing to another method?

Tags: c#

I have a LINQ list as follows

```
var lst =  (from entity in Entities
             join entity2 in E2.x equals Entities.x
                select entity);
```

2 . And um doing this after the above operation.
    return `lst.ToList<Object>()`

and from another method um accessing this list like this.

```
 List<Object> listObjects = new MyBO().GetAllEntities();
```

please note that number 2 is in the `GetAllEntities` method

but from `listObjects` by iterating `listObjects` I cannot access the members in individual element .

How to access the individual elements?

this is the output returned from `GetAllEntities()`

```
[0] { id= XCD1S100001, Type = EXPORT}
[1] { id= XSD1S100001, Type = IMPORT}
```

How to acccess `listObjects[0].getType()` or `listObjects[0].Type` because it won't give such a method.

Please need a hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first statement you use `var` keyword:

```
var lst =  (from entity in Entities select entity);
```

That makes `lst` the most suitable type, which is `IEnumerable<Entity>` (class name can be different, I'm just guessing here).

On the second approach you set the output as `List<object>` by yourself:

```
`return lst.ToList<Object>()`
```

and

```
List<Object> listObjects = new MyBO().GetAllEntities();
```

And that's why you can't directly get `Entity` class members there - `Object` instance does not have a property `Type`.

```
`return lst.ToList();`
```

hange it to `var` :

```
var listObjects = new MyBO().GetAllEntities();
```

You'll have to change method return type to `List<Entity>` as well.

Comment: Okay I cannot show my exact code but um taking values more than one entities using joins so my var list contains more than one entities . Thats why I have used an object list.

Answer (score 0):

What is type of `entity` in `Entities` collection? Why you are converting it to `List` of `object`? Try:

```
lst.ToList()
```

instead of:

```
lst.ToList<Object>()
```

Comment: um returning var lst so thats why I um converting .

Comment: What is 'um' ? Can you change it? So, you are not allowed to make change that i proposed to you?

Comment: um means I'am . sorry for the bad English